# How do i fix a Compile error/ Syntax error?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried understanding the logic of the loop and my sheet. I'm trying to get .pdf files transferred from a folder to another based off of what criteria is in an excel file, or column H = YES.
I get a syntax error down at the bottom of the code

```
**objFSO.CopyFile Source:=OldPath & Range("H"&CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType,
 Destination:=NewPath**


Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim OldPath As String
Dim NewPath As String
Dim sFileType As String

Dim bContinue As Boolean

bContinue = True
iRow = 2

' The Source And Destination Folder With Path

OldPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Spec\"
NewPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Dest\"

sFileType = ".pdf"

'Loop Through Column "H" To Pick The Files
While bContinue

If Len(Range("H" & CStr(iRow)).Value) = Yes Then
MsgBox "Files Copied"
bContinue = False

Else

Range("H" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "No"
Range("H" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = False

If Trim(NewPath) <> "" Then
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

'Check if destination folder exsists

If objFSO.FolderExists(NewPath) = False Then
MsgBox NewPath & "Does Not Exist"
Exit Sub
 End If

 'Using CopyFile Method to copy the files
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 objFSO.CopyFile Source:=OldPath & Range("H"&CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType,
 Destination:=NewPath

    End If
   End If
  End If

  iRow = iRow + 1

  Wend
 End Sub
```

CORRECT CODE listed below:

```
 Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim OldPath As String, NewPath As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'~~> File location bucklej
OldPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Specs\"
NewPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Dest\"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specification Listing")
Range("A2").Activate  '<--- to make sure we're starting at the right spot

For i = 2 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 8).Value = "YES" Then  '<--- correct, 8th column over
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
        fso.CopyFile OldPath & Cells(i, 1).Value & ".pdf", NewPath
    End If
Next i

ErrHandle:
ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = "File Not Found"
Resume Next



End Sub
```

Comment: You should really go back to your original question and edit that one with this current code instead of creating three posts. jus sayin.

Comment: you have too many 'end if' and the line where you have the error and the line below it should all be on one line

Comment: I deleted the extra End If and added the "Destination:=NewPath" to the row above and still get an error.

Comment: I'm getting a Run-time error '76': Path not found   and it's highlighting the same line now with yellow

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looking back at the second duplicate question and the snippet of code provided as an answer I see you said you were getting an error msg and the conversation went dead.  Expanding on that answer I was able to get the following to work using a test.txt.  You should be able to tweak this to your needs.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()


Dim OldPath As String, NewPath As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'~~> File location
OldPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\"
NewPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test\"

For i = 1 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "yes" Then
        fso.copyfile OldPath & Cells(i, 3).Value & ".txt", NewPath
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

UPDATE: I think (maybe) what the issue is is that since it's doing nothing the right sheet isn't being referenced.  Paste this updated code in the 'ThisWorkbook' and rename the sheet name in the code.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim OldPath As String, NewPath As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Test") <--rename to the sheet that has the parts numbers

'~~> File location
OldPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Spec\"
NewPath = "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Dest\"

For i = 1 To 1000
    If ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "YES" Then
         fso.CopyFile OldPath & Cells(i, 3).Value & ".pdf", NewPath
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

again, feel free to email me.

UPDATE: Final version with err handling thrown in

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim OldPath As String, NewPath As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'~~> File location bucklej
OldPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Specs\"
NewPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Dest\"

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specification Listing")
Range("A2").Activate

For i = 2 To 1000
    If Cells(i, 8).Value = "YES" Then
    On Error GoTo ErrHandle
        fso.CopyFile OldPath & Cells(i, 1).Value & ".pdf", NewPath
    End If
Next i

ErrHandle:
ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = "File Not Found"

Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I must be really dumb because now it's just not doing anything =(

Comment: "yes" is specific so depending it might need to be "YES" , also make sure this part "Cells(i, 3).Value" is the where you have the part number.

Comment: Yeah, I already made that change. Not sure why it would just sit there and do nothing.

Comment: In my example "Cells(i,2).Value" is the column where the "YES" should be and "Cells(i,3).Value" is where the part number/pdf file name should be.  Did you change this "& ".txt" to .pdf?

Comment: Yes I did those changes as well.

Comment: Can you share a sample file somewhere?  Google drive maybe

Comment: I actually can't share the file because of the information that it contains. Also don't have access to Google or email services at work only Outlook. I posted the code that I tried to fix up from your example above though.

Comment: So lets say the value of Cells(i,3) is Test123abc.  According to your edited version,  the path to copy is "C:\Users\bucklej\Desktop\Specs\Test123abcFull Tanker Part List COPY.xlsm"?

Comment: I thought that's where I was supposed to declare the file name. My mistake. So it's the path of the destination folder ?

Comment: No, In your case Cells(i,3) is going to be your part number which matches the name of the pdf in your Specs folder.  So... `fso.copyfile OldPath & Cells(i, 3).Value & ".pdf", NewPath` will take the OldPath address and combine it with the part number and the file extension and move it to NewPath address.  So if part number is 1234 you end up the code finding "C:\User\bucklej\Desktop\Specs\1234.pdf" and moving it to the new path.

Comment: Ok I follow that logic now and it makes sense to me looking at it. I did make the change and I did this before as well (I've tried a lot of combinations) but it doesn't run anything. The destination folder is still empty as there are multiple cells equaling yes the .pdf (spec) files should have been copied over.

Comment: Just curious, how are executing (running) the code?

Comment: I've clicked play in the actual code interface I've also tried clicking the button I've created and previously assigned the macro to. I get a whole lot of nothing.

Comment: this discussion is getting a bit long for here.  I have no problem if you want to email me directly , chrisopher@bornintx.com

Comment: Do you have the button on one sheet and the parts number on a separate sheet?

Comment: They're all on the same sheet. I sent you an email yesterday but it bounced back. I presume you forgot the "t" in christopher as I sent you another one this morning and it has yet to bounce back.